# Apache(2.4.7) LDAP URL authentication on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ldap, apache2.4

The following LDAP URL authentication is NOT working for mediawiki on ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, which is working on ubuntu 9.10 server.

cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/global.conf

```
<Directory /mediawiki>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        order allow,deny
        allow from all


AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Web Site Authentication: Login with your user id"
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
            AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.3:389/dc=mydomain,dc=net?uid"
            AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=net"
            AuthLDAPBindPassword secret
            Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Not working in the sense it's not prompting for authentication at all, just allows to access. No errors. There are many changes in Ubuntu 14.04, such as web root directory changed to /var/www/html in apache 2.4, `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative` is deprecated(that's why commented)....

If I paste the same code in `000-defaults` replacing /mediawiki with /var/www/html then it prompts for authentication for accessing `http://192.168.1.3`. But no effect for `http://192.168.1.3/mediawiki`

Am I missing anything in apache 2.4.7?. I'm confused, anybody has any idea?

Comment: The browser cache of one page which is already successfully authenticated affects the other site by not asking for authentication again. It's working now, full path is the key(and clearing the browser cache of other successfully authenticated site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory):

"Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching. In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters."

If mediawiki directory full path is /var/www/html/mediawiki try:

```
  <Directory /var/www/html/mediawiki>
```

If not, verify if you have forgot .htaccess file

Comment: I already tried it and it's now `/var/www/html/mediawiki' but the result is same. There is no .htaccess file under mediawiki.

Comment: Let me change the post with the complete path.

Comment: I tried with the full path `/var/www/html/mediawiki` before but replaced `order allow,deny` & `allow from all` with `Require all granted` to completely use 2.4 features. This caused apache not to show authentication box. It's working now full path is the key though.

Comment: Still wanted to know why it's not working with `Require all granted`. Any idea?

Comment: **Allow** and **deny** directive controls which hosts can or can't access an area of the server, **Require** tests whether an authenticated user is authorized according to a particular authorization provider and the specified restrictions. **Require all granted** means access is allowed unconditionally. If you put it before ldap directive maybe overrides authentication, let see [Beyond just authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#beyond)